# Mongodb 4.2 Brute Force Defense

Tags: mongodb, security

Is there any tool or configurations for mongodb server to protect against brute force attacks on the user credentials?

I found only [authFailedDelayMs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authFailedDelayMs) param witch Available in MongoDB Enterprise only (not my case)

Thanks

Comment: You can make the passwords longer.